# How to find the element position relative to it's parent to scroll it visible

Tags: jquery, position, scrolltop

I have a div with lots of elements inside it, and `overflow: scroll`. Then i want to be able to scroll the nth element in view. I set a fiddle to it, but I can't find the expression to get the element position relative to the parent.

http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/NXcTK/

I tried both `el.position().top` and `el.offset().top` but they don't work.

Note: `h / 2` is so the element is positioned in the middle of the div.

Comment: The problem is `cont.animate({scrollTop: (elementTop + h)});`. You want to subtract `h`, not add it. Looks like you may also want to add half the height of the element as well. So, `cont.animate({scrollTop: (elementTop - h)});`. P.S. `el.position().top` is correct in this case.

Comment: @BryanDowning i did this and now it works but only when the scroll bar is at the initial position.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a more stable solution that would work regardless of the offsetParent (which can change with the value of the [position](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) attribute), I would use offset() instead of position():

```
cont.animate({scrollTop: cont.scrollTop() + (el.offset().top - cont.offset().top)});
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 9):

Ok got it... just had to add the current scrollTop() to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/bortao/NXcTK/1/

```
var cont = $("#container");
var el = $(cont[0].children[index]);
var h = cont.height() / 2;
var elementTop = el.position().top;
var pos = cont.scrollTop() + elementTop - h;
cont.animate({scrollTop: pos});
```

Comment: This answer assumes that the offsetParent of the div you're scrolling to is the div that's overflowing. See @dlauzon's answer for an answer that will always work.